# how to bundle mysql2 to existing ruby on rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5

i am having a problem with installing mysql gem in ruby on rails. After i run bundle install this message appears:

```
Fetching mysql2 0.4.4
Installing mysql2 0.4.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory:

/Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
/Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -I
/Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0 -r
./siteconf20190606-13348-77enf9.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-  2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in
`try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.     (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:587:in
```

`try_cpp'
    from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1091:in`
block in have_header'
         from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-   2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in
   `block in checking_for'
   from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in`
block (2 levels) in postpone'
   from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-   2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in
   `open'
   from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in`
block in postpone'
    from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in
   `open'
   from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in`
postpone'
from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in
`checking_for'
from /Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1090:in`
have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Make sure the Ccode command line tools are installed by running `xcode-select --install` in the Terminal.

Comment: already installed

Comment: try 'gem uninstall mysql2',  'gem install mysql2' then remove gemfile.lock and finally 'bundle install' all while you're in the directory of your project

Comment: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..../Users/urijkunicyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: this error apperars: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6